# Can a quadcopter hover while tilted?

Tags: quadcopter

Is there a way to make a quadcopter maintain steady hovering (no lateral movement, constant altitude) while tilted left or right?  If so, how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a normal quadcopter configuration, if you tilt you will be pointing some of the lift force to the side. The only way to hover at a tilt, then, would be to somehow apply a counter force. A standard quadcopter can't do that itself, so it would need be an external force (tether, wind, etc).

Your other options are to use a nonstandard configuration such as actuated motors that let you tilt them individually or adding extra lateral motors.

Answer (score 3):

No. Once you're quad is tilted you are projecting the thrust of the motors at an angle which is not parallel to the z axis causing your quadcopter to move linearly along the x-y plane.

If you must hover while tilted, you can use stepper motors to keep the thrust projecting parallel to the z axis.

That would be an unusual quad though.

edit: spelling

Comment: "If you must hover while tilted, you can use stepper motors to keep the thrust projecting parallel to the z axis."  Do you mean that the quadrotors would need to also be tilted?

Comment: The motors would need to be kept parrallel to the z axis so that the thrust is pointing towards the ground. Yes the motors will have to be tilted to remain at the same orientation